# Why am I not able to login to DC LEGENDS?

Tags: dc-legends

I have downloaded **DC LEGENDS** from playstore and when I am trying to login to the game using my Google account it says "OUT OF SYNC".

It throws a pop-up saying "WE'VE HAD A SMALL SETBACK IN THE FIGHT AGAINST EVIL! PREPARE TO RESUME THE STRUGGLE!" and asks me to "RESTART" the game again and again.

I have uninstalled and installed the game, cleared the cache, killed the game process in the background and restarted the game but nothing seems to work!

What could be the issue?

Comment: I think you should contact the technical support for that game: community.wbgames.com/t5/Support/bd-p/DCL-Support

Comment: @Fabian it was quite useless. They don't seem to have any solution. Many people are facing this issue and it is still unresolved. :(

Comment: What was their answer? Did you pay for the game? If yes, you can insist on giving you either a helpful answer or your money back.

Comment: DC Legends is a free game with in-app purchases. I'm still following them up. I just wish that someone here knew what could be the issue.

Comment: Yes, your question is valid here, I just suggested contacting the support as another way of getting a solution.